# Is an answer considered a "post" for the badges requiring you to delete a post?

Tags: support, badges

For the Disciplined and Peer Pressure badges, it says you must delete your own +3 or -3 post, respectively. Are "posts" only questions, or questions and answers?

Comment: I would suggest you to not delete an +3 answer just to win the badge

Comment: @leo_ap it's perfectly valid to delete an upvoted answer if it is no longer relevant. I deleted an upvoted more than +3 answer because it was entirely outdated and obsolete, useless to anyone who may stumble upon it. Got the badge and wasn't previously aware of Disciplined.

Comment: I think @leo_ap was suggesting not to do it just for the badge, which I agree.

Comment: You can get these badges by just deleting an immediately undeleting- so these are pretty useless badges as it stands right now and bring no harm/use.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Both question and answer are considered 'posts'. The [create posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege doesn't mention this directly, but it's pretty obvious. I got both these badges on Stack Overflow by deleting answers.

Answer (score 12):

Both questions and answers are considered to be posts. So yes, you'll earn that badge if you delete your answer with a score equal to or greater than 3.